# dot sign's meaning in git checkout command

Tags: git, git-checkout

if I use git command like this:

```
git checkout -- .
```

I know its effect is to discard all unstaged files everywhere.

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of the dot sign (.) in this command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dot stands for the current directory. The command you've mentioned means: Do a git checkout of the current directory (recursively). The double-dashes separate options from filespecs (like `.`).

Comment: Note that this is a path specifier common to most Unix-like file systems, it isn't Git-specific. `.` is always the current directory, `..` is always the parent directory.

Answer (score 3):

The dot (`.`) refers to the current working directory.

You are asking git to checkout the current directory from the **checked out branch**. The double-dash is used to separate references, such as `master` or `HEAD` from file paths, such as `myfile.cpp`.