# Git: How to checkout all committed .css files in specific directory?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I added and deleted a bunch of files in `/webroot/modules/mod_menu` and I want to get all my .css files back from my last commit.  Unfortunately, I've deleted them and I don't remember their names.

If I try to do

```
git checkout HEAD^ /webroot/modules/mod_menu/*.css
```

it fails with a message like

```
error: pathspec '/webroot/modules/mod_menu/css_5XB5aQOGzDUVxnwtHDXg0AJDjmjZbe2Sh1K2BEkR5cM.css' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '/webroot/modules/mod_menu/css_foYlSNpOa-3y78f5xFwefA_kiFD67qfm6I1kXpro1XI.css' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '/webroot/modules/mod_menu/css_n7aK8s-ciXhQyEYWNOJtISbWxtxQiQvnD-N_xWUtD5A.css' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

That makes sense: the files it is trying to checkout are new ones, not the files that were in my previous commit.  But if I don't know the names of the files, how do I check them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [checkout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) has this in the SYNOPSIS section

```
git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>…]
```

Looks like you're missing the `--` between `<tree-ish>` and `<paths>`.  The following should work.

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- /webroot/modules/mod_menu/*.css
```

---

> what is that -- ? ...

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275475/164966) *The double-dash is used to separate references, such as `master` or `HEAD` from file paths...*

Comment: what is that `--`? sometimes it seems synonymous with `HEAD` and sometimes.. it doesn't.

Comment: @doub1ejack Updated answer to include -- information.  It's never synonymous with `HEAD`.  `HEAD` is just the default when the `<tree-ish>` argument is omitted.