# meaning of the command "git checkout ."

Tags: git, git-checkout

While I understand that the command in the title is akin to undo the changes to the current repository, I am unable to understand how it actually works or how to read the command. Any leads would be a great help.

Comment: Pleas read any git tutorial, then you will understand what is git checkout, and it's not always undo changes

Comment: @darvark yes I do understand a checkout isn't undoing changes always, but when the git checkout command is succeeded by a dot (.), the explanations were a little ambiguous. I guess I wasn't clear on the command.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275452/dot-signs-meaning-in-git-checkout-command

Comment: One other noteworthy item: `git checkout <path>` does not undo changes to the *repository* but rather replaces files in the *work-tree*. The *repository* is the underlying Git database of commits. The work-tree (which is mostly a separate thing from the repository, although there's normally one work-tree associated with any given repository clone) is where you use and edit files in the normal form the computer knows how to deal with, instead of Git's special internal-only form.

Answer (score 2):

> git checkout with `<paths>` [...] is used to restore modified or
>   deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace
>   paths with the contents from a named  (most often a
>   commit-ish).

See [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), especially [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-p--patchlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) and [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation): `.` is treated as `<pathspec>` in your case, adressing the current directory. The current `HEAD` revision of all files in the given `<pathspec>`, so in your case everything in your base directory, are checked out.

Answer (score -3):

git-checkout - Switch branches or restore working tree files

Example: 
git checkout -b [branch]