# What does this Command do " git checkout -- . "

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am beginner wit using git and I wanna know What this git command means

```
git checkout -- .
```

I know that git checkout  is for switching between branches but I don't know whta the above options means I tried to look on toturials but I didn't options like this one

Comment: It reverts the files in your working copy to the state of the checked-out revision (without touching untracked files). Basically discards your uncommitted (unstaged) changes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713/14955

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dot sign's meaning in git checkout command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275452/dot-signs-meaning-in-git-checkout-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-checkout%5D+%22git+checkout+--+.%22+double+dashes+dot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-checkout%5D+%22git+checkout+--+.%22

Comment: Don't feel bad, as `git checkout` is the source of much confusion for both newcomers and seasoned Git users. So much so that Git 2.23 recently split `git checkout` into two subcommands, `switch` and `restore`, each taking on a more focused responsibility than `checkout`. More details at https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/08/git-2-23-switch-restore/

Comment: The `--` separator in git commands separates file or directory paths from the rest. So, `git checkout -- paths` will only checkout `paths` provided after the the separator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I understood the meaning of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `--` nor `.` are git-specific:

> The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `'-'` character.

(from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash/11378).

`.` is the current directory.

> git checkout is for switching between branches

If you look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout, this command has the form

> `git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​`

so it

> Overwrite[s] paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).

"Paths" are `.` (the current directory) and "the `<tree-ish>`" is `HEAD` (the current commit Git points to), because you didn't specify another.

Answer (score 0):

It checks out the current directory and subdirectories.

```
tymtam@x:/mnt/c/tmp/x$ git status

        modified:   x.txt
        modified:   z/z1.txt
        modified:   z/z2/z2_1.txt

tymtam@x:/mnt/c/tmp/x$ cd z                // changing to subdirectory
tymtam@x:/mnt/c/tmp/x/z$ git checkout -- .
tymtam@x:/mnt/c/tmp/x/z$ git status

        modified:   ../x.txt
```

*(I removed git chatter for brevity)*

Comment: `git status -sb` can really cut away the chatter :)